# What’s wrong in this merge operation?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sql-merge

I am performing a MERGE operation in Oracle 11g, but they are returning more rows than the expected.

```
create table sales(product varchar2(20),month date, amount number(10))
insert into sales values('LG','01-Jan-17',20000);
insert into sales values('sony','01-Jan-18',22000);
insert into sales values('panasonic', '22-dec-17',18000);

create table sales_history(product varchar2(20),month date, amount number(10))
insert into sales_history values('sony', '22-dec-17',24000);
insert into sales_history values('panasonic', '22-dec-17',18000);

select * from sales;
select * from sales_history

merge into sales_history sh using(select product,month,amount from sales)s
on (s.product=sh.product)
when matched then update set sh.month=s.month,sh.amount=s.amount
when not matched then insert(sh.product,sh.month,sh.amount)
values(s.product,s.month,s.amount);
```

And I tried to do the same query in Pl/SQL which will give me the same results but it is returning more rows that is duplicated rows.Why is it so?

```
set serveroutput on
declare
s_product varchar2(20);
s_month date;
s_amount number(10);
p_product s_product%type;
m_month s_month%type;
a_amount s_amount%type;

cursor sc1 is
select product,month,amount from sales;
cursor shc2 is
select product,month,amount from sales_history;

begin
open sc1;
open shc2;
loop <<l1>>
fetch sc1 into s_product,s_month,s_amount;
fetch shc2 into p_product,m_month,a_amount;
if s_product = p_product then
  if s_month <> m_month then
  update sales_history set month = s_month where product = s_product;
  end if;
  if s_amount <> a_amount then
  update sales_history set amount = s_amount where product = s_product;
  end if;
else
  INSERT INTO  sales_history(product, month, amount)
  SELECT product, month, amount FROM sales;
  dbms_output.put_line('DATA IS UPDATED');
end if;
exit when sc1%notfound;
exit when shc2%notfound;
end loop l1;
close sc1;
close shc2;
end;

select * from sales_history
```

Comment: The Merge query is returning as much rows as you have wrote it to. It will always return the number of sales since you are doing an action for each row, either updating or inserting.

If you have a desired outcome, please update the question with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried executing the mentioned case in [Oracle 12c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Releases_and_versions) and it is working. Please see the output mentioned below:

```
create table sales(product varchar2(20),month date, amount number(10))
```

> Affected rows: 0 
> Time: 0.012s

```
insert into sales values('LG','01-Jan-17',20000)
```

> Affected rows: 1 
> Time: 0.003s

```
insert into sales values('sony','01-Jan-18',22000)
```

> Affected rows: 1 
> Time: 0.004s

```
insert into sales values('panasonic', '22-dec-17',18000)
```

> Affected rows: 1 
> Time: 0.003s

```
create table sales_history(product varchar2(20),month date, amount number(10))
```

> Affected rows: 0 
> Time: 0.004s

```
insert into sales_history values('sony', '22-dec-17',24000)
```

> Affected rows: 1 
> Time: 0.002s

```
insert into sales_history values('panasonic', '22-dec-17',18000)
```

> Affected rows: 1 
> Time: 0.003s

```
merge into sales_history sh using(select product,month,amount from sales)s
on (s.product=sh.product)
when matched then update set sh.month=s.month,sh.amount=s.amount
when not matched then insert(sh.product,sh.month,sh.amount)
values(s.product,s.month,s.amount)
```

> Affected rows: 3 
> Time: 0.015s

Comment: i would suggest to use Merge query as it will take less time as compared to PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: Please, provide code as snippet rather than as screenshot.

Comment: I used the same code as mentioned above in the question so to show successful execution i added screen shot. Now, I have replaced the screen shot with code.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
if s_product = p_product then
<<your code>>
else
<<your code>>
```

And when the first product name is *sony* from table *sales*, it does match with *sony* in *sales_history* and give the desired output, but also it does not match with the other entry in *sales_hist* and execute the *else* part of your code which is insert. This gives you multiple row as result.

See the below output. I tried with multiple dbms output. The *else* part is getting executed when *sony* is different from *panasonic* and so on.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
s_product varchar2(20);
s_month date;
s_amount number(10);
p_product s_product%type;
m_month s_month%type;
a_amount s_amount%type;

cursor sc1 is
select product,month,amount from sales;
cursor shc2 is
select product,month,amount from sales_history;

begin
open sc1;
open shc2;
loop <<ll>>
fetch sc1 into s_product,s_month,s_amount;
fetch shc2 into p_product,m_month,a_amount;
dbms_output.put_line('outside if');
dbms_output.put_line(s_product);
dbms_output.put_line(p_product);
if s_product = p_product then
  dbms_output.put_line(p_product);
  if s_month <> m_month then
  dbms_output.put_line(m_month);
  update sales_history set month = s_month where product = s_product;
  end if;
  if s_amount <> a_amount then
  update sales_history set amount = s_amount where product = s_product;
  end if;
else
  INSERT INTO  sales_history(product, month, amount)
  SELECT product, month, amount FROM sales;
  dbms_output.put_line('DATA IS UPDATED');
end if;
exit when sc1%notfound;
exit when shc2%notfound;
end loop l1;
close sc1;
close shc2;
end;
```

##### Output

```
outside if
LG
sony
DATA IS UPDATED
outside if
sony
panasonic
DATA IS UPDATED
outside if
panasonic
panasonic
panasonic
```